# Using a Loop to add ActiveListeners in one class for a button in multiple instances of another class

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, java-8, actionlistener

I have a class called `InstructionBlock`, which is a JPanel
On my main form, which is a JFrame, I've created 6 instances of `InstructionBlock`.  I need to have my main form do something based on a button being pressed in the instances of `InstructionBlock` and it needs to know which instances had the button pressed.

I have the following code in the class `InstructionBlock`:

```
public void InstBlockAddActionListener(ActionListener al) {
    CheckMarkClicked.addActionListener(al);
}
```

I've add the instances of `InstructionBlock` to my main form as follows:
`ArrayList<InstructionBlock>  instructionPane = new ArrayList<>();
 int i;`

```
for (int i = 0; i<6;i++) {
       instructionPane.add(new InstructionBlock());
       InstructionLayer.add(instructionPane.get(i));
    }
```

Now here is where I have an issue:

```
for (i = 0; i<6;i++) {
        instructionPane.get(i).InstBlockAddActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {InstructionCheckMarkButtonPressed(i+1);});
    }
```

When I hit the 1st button, I expected to pass a value of 1, but I'm passing a value of 7

I know I can do it as follows:

```
    instructionPane.get(0).InstBlockAddActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {InstructionCheckMarkButtonPressed(1);});
    instructionPane.get(1).InstBlockAddActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {InstructionCheckMarkButtonPressed(2);});
    instructionPane.get(2).InstBlockAddActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {InstructionCheckMarkButtonPressed(3);});
    instructionPane.get(3).InstBlockAddActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {InstructionCheckMarkButtonPressed(4);});
    instructionPane.get(4).InstBlockAddActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {InstructionCheckMarkButtonPressed(5);});
    instructionPane.get(5).InstBlockAddActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {InstructionCheckMarkButtonPressed(6);});
```

But I don't know why the loop isn't working.  Is there another way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for (i = 0; i<6;i++) {
    instructionPane.get(i).InstBlockAddActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {InstructionCheckMarkButtonPressed(i+1);});
}
```

You must be making `i` a field of the class for this to compile, and by doing this, you set it to 7 and only 7 after this for loop has finished. To solve this, don't use a class field but rather an inner final variable, something like:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    final int finalIndex = j + 1;
    instructionPane.get(j).InstBlockAddActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {
        InstructionCheckMarkButtonPressed(finalIndex);
    });
}
```

As a side recommendation, and in order to help us now and to help yourself in the future, please edit your code and change your variable names to conform with Java [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: That worked great.  Thank you.  I try to keep to the naming convention, but bad habits die hard.  Buttons and controls on a form would also start with a lower case?  I guess they are variables, but I always thought of them as "Proper Names"